# App icon with heart inside of a square speech bubble!

Tags: applications, notification-icons

My father sent me a screenshot and on the notifications bar I saw an icon with a heart inside a square speech bubble (please see attached image). I've been looking for this specific icon online and from what app it belongs to, but I haven't found anything. I am not sure if it could be from either an diet and exercise app he's been using or something else, specially because my mom has been suspecting of his behavior lately. An insight of what a possible app could be would be nice.[image: app icon with heart inside of a speech bubble]

Answer (score 3):

Research on the internet indicates this is a "like" icon for a message posted through the GroupMe app. See if this app is available on the phone used by your father.

Here is the [Google Play page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groupme.android) for the app.

Here is the [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/37p0hc/help_figuring_out_what_app_this_notification_is/) I found indicating the purpose of the icon.